# For-loop is executed only once?

Tags: java, for-loop, insertion-sort

I'm implementing Insertionsort for university. My code works in theory, but my for-loop is executed only once instead of books.size() (which is 5, I've tested that). I tried it using the number 5, but it won't work and I'm kind of desperate because I can't seem to find the error.

Here is my code:

```
    static void sort(LinkedList<Book> books)
    {
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < books.size(); i++)
        {
            Book temp = books.get(i);
            books.remove(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < books.size(); j++) {
                if (books.get(j).compareTo(temp) > 0) {
                    books.add(j, temp);
                    return;
                }
            }
            books.add(temp);
        }
    }
```

The compareTo function of the Book-Class looks like the following:

```
public int compareTo(Book other)
{
    int iAutor = autor.compareTo(other.getAutor());

    if (iAutor != 0)
        return iAutor;
    else
    {
        int iTitel = titel.compareTo(other.getTitel());

        if (iTitel != 0)
            return iTitel;
        else
        {
            if (this.auflage < other.getAuflage())
                return -1;
            else if (this.auflage > other.getAuflage())
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I simply blind?

Comment: that inner `return;` seems suspicious...

Comment: I'm with that @Sparta fellow!

Comment: I guess you checked that the compare function does bit return a value greater zero in the first iteration  ?

Comment: @Sparta Well, that happens when you code tired .__. You're right, that's it. But if I exchange it with a `break` it adds every entry twice. Can I do something about it without outsourcing it in a seperate `insert` function?

Comment: @Valentin explain to us what you are trying to achieve. We might even suggest you some logic insights..

Comment: @Sparta I'm trying to do Insertionsort in a `LinkedList`. Therefore I wrote a function to compare Books in the Books class. I now need to sort a list of books. Therefore I save the first entry as a temp value, then I remove it from the list. I now gor through the list from right to left and see if it is greater than the last. If it is, I add it to the list.

Comment: Apart from what's been said already, your loops don't look right. Try righting down how the insertion sort algorithm works in plain language. Visualize it in your mind. Then, and only then, put it into code. You'll see where you went wrong. (As a hint, consider that you have two sections in your list: a sorted one and an unsorted one. Each time through your outer loop, take one element from the unsorted section and insert it into the correct place in the sorted section.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap return for break and fix the logic to avoid adding the book twice. There may be more elegant ways than this, but it should work:

```
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < books.size(); i++)
    {
        Book temp = books.get(i);
        books.remove(i);
        bool added = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < books.size(); j++) {
            if (books.get(j).compareTo(temp) > 0) {
                books.add(j, temp);
                added = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!added) {
            books.add(temp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works fine now, thank you :) Only problem is that I still have a problem with my `compareTo` as it seems, because the output is:

Eins, Abraham, 1. Auflage
Eins, Bebraham, 2. Auflage
Zwei, Bebraham, 2. Auflage
Eins, Bebraham, 3. Auflage
Drei, Zebraham, 3. Auflage

Which is correct but for the fourth entry ._.

Comment: I would guess that's because you're modifying the collection as you iterate: since the order gets mooved but you are inspecting each index one at a time, you may not compare enough pairs to sort properly. Instead (and maybe this is the real answer) you should implement a Comparator<Book> (using your compareTo method) and use Collections.sort(), which is easier overall anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out how to solve it, just if someone has the same problem (don't think that will happen, but it's a good habit I hope).

As @Klitos Kyriacou pointed out right, I had a twist in my thoughts about the process of Insertionsorting.

The solution is changing the loops in the following:

```
     static void sort(LinkedList<Book> books) {

    Book temp;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < books.size(); counter++) {
        temp = books.get(counter);

        for (int position = 0; position < counter; position++)
        {
            if (temp.compareTo(books.get(position)) < 0)
            {
                books.remove(counter);
                books.add(position, temp);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```